# Laplace transform inversion

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, laplace-transform

I have a probability distribution that is defined through it's Laplace transform by :

$$L(t) = \mathbb E(e^{-tX}) =  e^{1 - \frac{1+t}{t}\ln(1+t)}$$

Using R and the *invLT* package, i have a numerical inversion that is quite convincing. Then, i tried through *fitdistrplus* to estimate the resulting density by MLE on weibull, gamma, pareto and burr models, which produced the following plots:

[image: Graphs of the fitdistr results]

It look like the density that i am looking for lives on the positive real axis, has only one mode, and behave quite nicely.

My goal is now to recover an analytic expression for the coresponding CDF (at least). I tried doing the Broomwitch integration as [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform#Mellin%27s_inverse_formula) suggests, but i am not skilled enough in complex integration to make it through...

Do you think that an analytic expression could be recovered for this CDF ? How should i proceed ?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{\AMScd}$$\require{\mathabx}$$\newcommand\al{\alpha}\newcommand\be\beta$ $\newcommand{\Conv}{\mathop{\ast}}$Mathematica cannot invert this transform:

[image]

---

However, for real $t>0$ we can write
\begin{align}
L(t)&=\exp\Big\{1-\frac1t\,\int_0^t(1+\ln(1+u))\,du\Big\} \\ 
&=\exp\Big\{-\frac1t\,\int_0^t\ln(1+u)\,du\Big\} \\ 
&=\exp\Big\{-\int_0^1\ln(1+zt)\,dz\Big\} \\ 
&=\prod_{j=1}^n\exp\Big\{-\int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n}\ln(1+zt)\,dz\Big\} \\ 
&=\prod_{j=1}^n\exp\Big\{-\frac1n\,\ln\Big(1+\frac jn\,t\Big)+O\Big(\frac{t/n^2}{1+t(j-1)/n}\Big)\Big\} \\ 
&=\exp\{O(t/n)\}\prod_{j=1}^n\Big(1+\frac jn\,t\Big)^{-1/n}. 
\end{align}
Note that $[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto(1+\beta t)^{-\alpha}$ is the Laplace transform of the density (say $f_{\al,\be}$) of the gamma distribution with parameters $\al,\be$. Thus, the inverse Laplace transform in question is the density function
$$f:=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\DeclareMathOperator{\st}{\ast}}\Conv_{j=1}^n f_{1/n,\,j/n},$$
an infinite infinitesimal convolution of gamma densities. In particular, $f$ is indeed supported on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Yeah, that is where it came from, this is the 'continuous' convolution of all exponentials with rates between 0 and 1. The Laplace transform converges to this nice expression, so i was hoping we could obtain something for the CDF / the density.

Comment: An explicit expression seems very unlikely, taking in particular into account that Mathematica cannot produce it.

Comment: I finaly used a numerical approach to simulate the distribution (wich is what i wanted), and it 'seems' to be OK. However, a full expression would have been better. Sorry for not telling you where it came from and wasting your time, and thanks anyway for your oppinon ! Although the result is negative, i'll still accept your ansewr ;)

Comment: All right. I am curious, how did you simulate the distribution?

Comment: Hahaha. As i said on the upper post, I used the `invLT::iv.OpC` function in R. It does a numerical inverse laplace transform to recover observations of the density; Then i  cumsumed to obtain a discretisation of the CDF. But this is not optimal if you only want to generate from the distribution, then you should take a look at this paper : https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-008-9103-x The coresonding code is there : https://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/msr/rlaptrans.html .

Comment: Finaly, do you know if taking a formal expansion of my LT would allow me to get an extension of the density as a formal serie ? In which case, controling the error might be doable. I do not know enough about inversions of Lts... But i still have https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BE%2F%281+%2B+t%29%5E%28%281+%2B+t%29%2Ft%29%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+100%7D%5D !

Comment: I don't know R and have never used it. However, I would guess that the scheme "Laplace transform->PDF->CDF->InverseCDF" would hardly be effective. I guess that approximating, with a large enough $n$, the distribution in question by the distribution of the sum of $n$ independent gamma random variables with the same small shape parameter could be much more effective. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1884.pdf on simulation of the gamma distribution with a small shape parameter.

Comment: I am not sure that your derivation is correct (or mine of the laplace transform might be wrong !). It is supposed to be the convolution of all exponentials with rates between 0 and 1, not all gammas with rate between zero and one and shape -> 0. The cumulant generating function was obtained as $K(-t) = -\mathbb E(ln(1+tU))$ where $U$ is a standard uniform. Anyway, maybe taking instead of $U$ a discrete uniform with enough atoms and convoluting might give me a better result, indeed.

Comment: I have re-checked the derivation. Apart from a few typos (now fixed), it seems to be correct, for the Laplace transform in your post. On the other hand, if you convolve infinitely many exponential distributions with means bounded away from $0$, you'll get the distribution supported at $\{\infty\}$. Also, you may be confusing the scale parameter with its reciprocal, the rate parameter. In my convolution formula, the scales are $\le1$ and hence the rates are $\ge1$.

Comment: Actually we do have the same: the correct discretisation of a uniform distribution has weights 1/n which is what you have, although the full 'continuous' convolutions convovles true exponentials (weight 1) as my interpretation said. Thanks a lot for taking the time, it is always a pleasure to get help from you (not the first time ;) )

Comment: All right, good to be of help.